How can I return a vector of structs in C++ using Emscripten and WebAssembly
I want to return to the javascript a type created in c++, called PlayerAction.
PlayerAction have two elements, Player, type int and Action, type int_64
I tried to do it the way below but it doesn't work, it returns a weird object.
My Code bellow in c++:
#include <emscripten/bind.h>
#include <vector>

using Player = int;
using Action = int64_t;

struct PlayerAction {
    Player player;
    Action action;

    bool operator==(const PlayerAction& other) const {
        return player == other.player && action == other.action;
    }
};

std::vector<PlayerAction> getAction() {
    std::vector<PlayerAction> action;
    
    PlayerAction action1 = {0, 2};
    PlayerAction action2 = {1, 4};
    
    action.push_back(action1);
    action.push_back(action2);
    
    return action;
}

// Bindings
EMSCRIPTEN_BINDINGS(my_module) {
    emscripten::value_object<PlayerAction>("PlayerAction")
        .field("player", &PlayerAction::player)
        .field("action", &PlayerAction::action);

    

    emscripten::function("getAction", &getAction);
    emscripten::register_vector<PlayerAction>("vector<PlayerAction>");
}


Html and Js:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Exemplo Emscripten</title>
    
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        var Module = {
            onRuntimeInitialized: function() {
                console.log(Module.getAction());
            }
        }
    </script>
    <script src="exemplo.js"></script>
</body>
</html>


